# Android : Button to open Navigation Layout not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am working on an Android application in which I am trying to integrate the Navigation Drawer. The navigation drawer is there, but there is no button for that to open or close it, I just have to drag it via a finger outside. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be nice.

To integrate the Drawer, I have an activity class, which I am extending instead of Activity to show the drawer within. 
Below is the class which is extended by all activities where I want a drawer.

Here is the RestaurantDrawerActivity class :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class RestaurantDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items/*
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<DrawerModel> navDrawerItems;
    private RestaurantDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_drawerlayout);

        toolbar  = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        System.out.println(toolbar == null);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {


       /* Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        System.out.println(toolbar == null);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.restaurant_nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.restaurant_drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurant_list_slidermenu);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<DrawerModel>();

            /*for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[i],
                        navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
            }*/

        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new RestaurantDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, RestaurantMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Still in development", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case 2:
                Intent addMenuCardIntent = new Intent(this, RestaurantMenu.class);
                startActivity(addMenuCardIntent);
                finish();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Still in development", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case 4:
                Intent logout = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                StaticRestTemplate.setJsessionid("");
                StaticRestTemplate.setLoggedInUser("");
                StaticRestTemplate.setReplyString("");
                startActivity(logout);
                finish();
                break;
            case 5:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item

            displayView(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/restaurant_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and toolbar.xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Here is the screenshot showing that the button is not there :

[image]

Comment: @Boss : Dont think so, here is the manifest, http://pastebin.com/SdNy61b9

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code line

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

To

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Sorry, that didnt change anything, no button yet.

Comment: Where you call public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) { } method ?

Comment: No theme in manifest, i have theme in styles.xml as    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>

Comment: I call the set method method in activity which needs drawer layout.

Comment: Please call it from onCreate() method in RestaurantDrawerActivity. It helps you.

Comment: @Borg Though the home button is a part of `ActionBar`, why do you use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` as `AppTheme`?

Comment: Which one should I use thenß

Comment: @Borg `Theme.AppCompat`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. But you've already tried with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and it didn't help, there may be yet other problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't use the `set()` method that these

```
// enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

two lines aren't executed.

I think these two lines (especially the first one) are needed to show the home button.

Comment: So, should I change their position or something?

Comment: @Borg I think put them in the `onCreate` or execute `set()` in there is good.

Comment: These lines should be inside onCreate method. Also remove your Toolbar code (or comment it for the time being). To use the default ActionBar, your theme must have an ActionBar, example -> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: @user3641702 : That didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll help but I've noticed the lack of super.onDrawerClosed and super.onDrawerOpened calls in your code and you could get some errors because of that. So, try changing your code to:

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.